# DYMO LabelWriter get print callback

Tags: javascript, dymo

Is there way to get callback from the DYMO that a label is successfully printed?

I am using DYMO JS library and it provides "true" even when the printing fails. I need to lock or delete my print jobs once I get success callback from the DYMO printer.

Comment: did you find the answer?

Comment: @MahendraPratap No

Comment: @MahendraPratap there is now an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You may use the method `printAndPollStatus` on the `label` object.

Example taken from [here](http://www.labelwriter.com/software/dls/sdk/samples/js/PrintMeThatLabel/pl.html):

```
// print and get status
var printJob = label.printAndPollStatus(printer.name, null, labelSet.toString(), function(printJob, printJobStatus)
{
   // output status
   var statusStr = 'Job Status: ' + printJobStatus.statusMessage;
   var result = (printJobStatus.status != dymo.label.framework.PrintJobStatus.ProcessingError 
                && printJobStatus.status != dymo.label.framework.PrintJobStatus.Finished);

   // reenable when the job is done (either success or fail)
   printButton.disabled = result;

   return result;           
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Hi @Adam. Thanks for the answer. But the status always shows "not implemented" even on the Dymo page you shared.